# empty function not working while checking form field array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of html textbox element with name say `date_field[]`. There could be multiple fields in the form. After submission of the form to check whether at least one of the textbox is not empty, I used -

```
<?php
if(empty($_POST["date_field"])){
        echo "Is empty";
    }else{
        echo "is not empty";
    }
?>
```

It echoed `is not empty` no matter whether I fill or I didn't fill this `date_field`.

P.S. If I printed the form value using `print_r`

If I didn't put value

```
[followup_date] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )
```

if I put value

```
[followup_date] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2012-12--14
        )
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: for the first one: `if(empty($_POST["date_field"][0])){ ..` or a loop for multiple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "empty" array contains an empty string:

```
array(0 => '')
```

That's not an *empty* array. The only "empty" array is `array()`.

You may want to run it through [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter), which removes all elements evaluating to `false` (which also includes `"0"`, be careful).

Comment: as this field is suppose to enter Date, I guess I can safely use `array_filter` ??

Answer (score 2):

The array is not empty since it will contain one element per non-disabled form field (even when those fields are empty).

You could use the array_filter function as mentioned by @deceze, but remember that this would also remove some elements which a human wouldn't consider to be empty.

Therefore I'd rather run through the array myself and check if all elements are empty in the matter that you want. For example:

```
function all_is_empty(array $subject)
{
    foreach($subject as $value)
        if(str_len($value) > 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Usage:

```
if(all_is_empty($_POST["date_field"]))
{
    echo "Is empty";
}
else
{
    echo "is not empty";
}
```

If this was me, I'd probably also combine this with checking that all the fields were valid. So if you know all the fields in that array should be dates, check that they actually are :)

Comment: Or, you know... `array_filter($array, 'strlen')`... :)

Comment: Yeah, I saw the callback option after I wrote this, but I still think this would be a cleaner way. It's more obvious what the purpose is in this case with `all_is_empty($s)` than `empty(array_filter($s, 'str_len')`. At least I think so :)